# VS 2005 Class Diagram View format

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I have generated class diagram by gight clicking and selecting generate class diagram usign VS 2005. There are nearly 300 class in my project . The class diagram that i have created is not in expanded view. I have to manually expand the class diagrams to view the members. Is there any way to expand the classdiagrams that are created .

Regards,
Jebli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it. I have selected all the class and right clicked and then selected expand. Thanks.

Regards,
Radha A